# how to store objects in DB in node.js

Tags: javascript, gmail-api

I'm making an app using Gmail JS API to fetch emails and store data in DB for attachments, so I do not have to make API calls again and again to get a single attachment for a particular message. I need to store `payload` object in DB. Can anyone guide me how can I store it in Node.js? 
My code looks like below:

```
let data = {
    'message_id': msg_id,
    'thread_id': thread_id,
    'payload': JSON.stringify(message.payload)
}
$.post(url, data, function(result){
     // perform anything on result
});
```

And in Node.js I'm running this query (MySQL).

```
 connection.query(`INSERT INTO email_payloads (message_id, payload, thread_id) VALUES('${message_id}', '${payload}', '${thread_id}')`, (err, result)=>{
  if(err){
      res.send(err);
  }

  });
```

I'm converting payload object into JSON string and saving it in DB successfully. Problem is that I don't think it is being stored completely. It's eliminating some of its data. Column type is `LONGTEXT` and I checked payload string length before and after, and there is a difference.

**Length Before Saving in DB:** 25461

**Length After Saving in DB:** 25445

as you can see some of its data is missed and I'm getting error while parsing that string fetched from DB. Is it DB problem? or is there any limit on sending big data with `POST` request? I don't think `POST` has any size limit. Or is there any other way to serialize/unseralize object like PHP in JS? Please help me in this.

Thanks.

Comment: As we can see? We can't see. Provide us a [mcve].

Comment: which DB are you using ? and share the code for how you're storing in Node.js ?

Comment: @KamalakannanJ Please see now. question is updated and I'm using MySQL DB.

Comment: If you're JSON has quotes, it can cut off your data sooner than you expect. Be sure to escape quotes or use binds.

Comment: @JM-AGMS can you please guide me how to do that?

Comment: Are you getting the same payload in your Node.js ? If yes, print the data before and after insert. And also the difference is very minimal which may be due to whitespace removal.

Comment: @KamalakannanJ yes, Im getting same payload. What is returned by API is exactly being passed in Node.js. Length is same in my angular app and node.js. But there is slight difference after inserting in DB.

Comment: That's because your payload may have empty spaces or numbers as strings("12345678" as string is 8 bytes while as Number it's just 4 bytes.)